# RSA Encryption/decryption within windows crypto library dll?

Tags: windows, dll, cryptography

I'm in a situation that I need to use AES-256, SHA1,2 and RSA, but these functions need to be loaded from an intrinsic windows dll file (something like cryptoAPI in advapi32.dll, which can be found in C:\Windows\system32).

I've found almost everything I need in advapi32.dll except RSA encryption. So,do you know any other crypto libraries from windows (XP2 should be supported)?

In the worst case, any free external crypto library in dll format is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by this "RSA encryption" that would be missing from Crypto API?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, RSA Encryption/Decryption are not supported (at least, directly) by cryptoAPI. The best I can find is the using of function "CryptExportKey", that will RSAEncrypt the hash of my input. Or am I wrong? Please light up my situation.

Comment: RSA Encryption, the asymmetric encryption algorithm that is used to encrypt the preMasterSecret in keyExchange step of an SSL/TLS Session.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem you have. See here for what RSA you need in TLS: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/what-key-exchange-mechanism-should-be-used-in-tls. This RSA key exchange does exist in Crypto API.

Comment: I'm implementing TLS with VB6, so I need RSA function to encrypt premasterSecret by publicKey. You gave me a thread about the secure aspect of many algorithms, RSA is one among that. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using .Net or a 3rd party component, I've found no reasonable solution for RSA in windows. So, about .Net, please see klugerama's last comment. About 3rd party component, I've found a great library for VB6 user, which will works in Windows XP without the installation of .NetFramework 2.0+. It's called VBCOrLib :

http://www.kellyethridge.com/vbcorlib/

Alternative solution for C++ users was Crypto++ as suggested by RaptorFactor.

Thanks for all your helps !

Answer (score 1):

[RSA encryption/decryption is supported by the CryptoAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI:

```
[...]It is a set of dynamically linked libraries that provides an abstraction layer which isolates programmers from the code used to encrypt the data.
```

So, advapi32.dll ≠ CryptoAPI. However, since it is an abstraction of the CryptoAPI functions, linking to that dll should expose whichever functionality you need, algorithm-agnostic.

To answer the question strictly, the CSP library file that handles RSA stuff is rsaenh.dll.  However, I'm not sure why you should need to know that necessarily; like @SimonMourier (and I) stated, CryptoAPI handles linking to the appropriate CSP.  Calling the appropriate functions from advapi32.dll should allow the use of a variety of algorithms, including RSA.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I need to use a concrete RSA function DIRECTLY like this : encrypted = RSA(rawData) but not some mechanisms with RSA behind the scene (which are what cryptoAPI ALWAYS provides) such as "CryptExportKey"...etc - I can not find the way to use RSA Encryption/Decryption directly !

Comment: Thanks, but that microsoft's example gave me some symmetric encryption, not RSA.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really that averse to using the built-in Windows stuff then there's always Crypto++. It supports being compiled as a DLL afaik. http://www.cryptopp.com/

Comment: What a pity, i'm using VB :). I've just found out VBCorLib.dll. Thanks for your suggestion.